# Least Square method

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I have some data and would like to find the best paramter of a half normal distribution (in this case the sigma) based on the method of least square.

I have already checked the ML results (based on the article in the english wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-normal_distribution ) but somehow I would like to have a second estimation for :)

So could this be done within Mathematica?

---

my data:

{1.53, 4.24, 5.26, 5.25, 8.37, 3.51, 5.58, 4.61, 3.38, 7.19, 1.32, \
5.05, 28.93, 30.97, 5.6, 13.22, 26.29, 2.83, 5.36, 0.64, 4.46, 2.94, \
1.07, 2.04, 3.79, 5.63, 4.7, 3.79, 10.49, 7.41, 7.41, 9.61, 9.61, \
4.51, 3.83, 8.83, 15.95, 14.05, 4.88, 21.14, 12.42, 7.65, 1.77, 7.36, \
11.46, 2.63, 3.82, 3.23, 3.81, 3.02, 8.76, 9.09, 16.86, 8.08, 7.29, \
6., 12.91, 4.71, 4.73, 4.62, 16.43, 1.83, 7.42, 2.97, 5.71, 2.62, \
2.65, 1.62, 1.57, 1.86, 2.54, 3.49, 4.75, 4.38, 4.79, 3.3, 0.75, \
1.44, 3.58, 5.35, 5.35, 2.21, 4.93, 2.73, 2.31, 3.97, 4.88, 0.51, \
3.04, 3.76, 1.3, 1.38, 2.17, 2.23, 0.02, 11.87, 1.32, 2.49, 2.54, \
21.19, 2.87, 9.41, 1.37, 5.91, 1.13, 2.23, 2.34, 5.72, 10.58, 9.32, \
3.45, 0.81, 15.67, 5.58, 7.63, 2.96, 7.07, 12.94, 0.18, 1.45, 8.46, \
1.08, 0.33, 0.87, 2.06, 1.41, 2.75, 2.49, 7.66, 0.45, 1.02, 5.4, \
2.86, 1.3, 0.06, 2.63, 2.63, 1.29, 1.3, 1.25, 18.85, 7.11, 11.72, \
9.88, 2.82, 1.73, 1.73, 1.38, 1.17, 1.99, 0.9, 1.3, 8.81, 1.19, 2.51, \
6.79, 3.61, 2.18, 2.18, 1.05, 0.85, 0.13, 0.8, 3.86, 1.29, 5.96, 0.6, \
2., 2.22, 2.24, 0.45, 1.61, 0.72, 0.18, 1.58, 2.78, 3.97, 0.11, 1.32, \
0.72, 0.93, 1.07, 1.41, 4.38, 1.08, 0.13, 1.76, 15.44, 15.44, 5.55, \
5.55, 1.76, 3.08, 1.17, 1.4, 14.31, 13.83, 2.54, 0.77, 0.8, 3.44, \
1.25, 1.25, 0.8, 0.8, 0.49, 6.43, 8.28, 1.35, 1.26, 0.74, 7.01, 0.57, \
3.02, 1.1, 34.42}

---

Look Gentlemen,

i have played a little bit with the theta and found a solution by try and error which fits at least visual much better as the theta calculated by ML (manually be me and the estimator by MMA).

the key point is there is not mathematical basis for me which underlies the result.

so has somebody an idea?

mel

[image]

---

here i would like to show the final result. 
It failed the chiquadrat test and somehow i could imagine
from the curve over the histogramm there is a better solution for :)

however Mathematica calculated the same theta than calculated by me manually :)

just a note: i know other distribution fits better (exponential one) but from the nature of the data i have some "feeling" they could be normal distributed so it thought about the halfnormalized

[image]

Comment: Have you searched the documentation for "least squares"?  What did you find?  Also, it's not clear what you want to do here as least squares are used to fit a function and it sounds like you have a distribution.  Then you need to use some representation of that distribution as a function (PDF, CDF, etc.)

Comment: Have you seen External links on the the particular page you claim?

Comment: Hello. i agree i want to fit my data to a PDF and one method is the least square for (beside the ML and the estimations of the moments). so i thought mathematica has an option for. the one the bracket i have already did manually.

Comment: to fit means to find the best estimation for the parameter

Comment: Here the relevant parts, has been extracted from the grid as a part of a function Estimator for theta by mathematica: FindDistributionParameters[data, HalfNormalDistribution[\[Theta]]]} Show [Histogram[{data}, {classWidth}, "ProbabilityDensity", ImageSize -> {820,530}, PlotRange -> All], Plot[PDF[HalfNormalDistribution[theta], x], {x, 0, Round[Max [data], 1]}, ImageSize -> {820, 530}, PlotRange -> All]]} theta has been calculated by me manually and doublechecked with Mathematica "FindDistributionParameters". the data are equal

Comment: Please read [the tour of this site](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) before posting anything else.  Let me quote the first item: *"This site is all about **getting answers**. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat."*  This is a questions and answers site where posts are expected to conform to a certain structure.  You have already posted 4 'answers' (!) none of which answer the question you originally asked.  Please do not do this, and in the future make sure that your questions are clearly and precisely phrased.

Comment: As mentioned, please do not use answers for additional information; click on the edit button below your question if you wish to add anything.

Answer (score 1):

If your data is really a random sample from a half-normal distribution, then maximum likelihood is an efficient use of the data.

An alternative is the “method of moments”.  The mean of a half-normal is $\sigma\sqrt{2/\pi}$ and the variance is $\sigma^2(1-2/\pi)$.  You could calculate the sample moments $\bar{x}$ and $s^2$, equate them to the true values, and solve for σ.  You would then pick the one you liked the best.  (Yes, I’m being facetious about which one you pick.)

Another alternative is a Bayesian estimator.  You can google “Bayesian half normal”  for a bunch of hits.

Your approach using a histogram is both good and bad.  The “good” is that it might show some lack of fit which would suggest that you don’t really have random samples from a half-normal distribution and, therefore, it is pointless to estimate a parameter for a distribution from which you’re not sampling.  The “bad” is that even if you have samples from a half-normal distribution, choosing the fit that looks good to you throws away any support based on statistical theory (such as confidence intervals).

Comment: thank you. i will take a look at your thoughts. yes my data is a random sample for which i search the best distribution for. from my feeling the data are generally normal distributed (basically movements between some points) but the sign depends just from the side i look. so if there is a + or - just depends from the point of view for the observer. so i came to to result that absolute values and so halfnormalized is one potential distribution...basically i have checked exponential one which passed the chiquadrat test-to-fit but from the nature of data i would prefer to have a normal one.

Comment: regards the calculation. i calculate for instance the mean of the data (x') and set them to x' = sigma * squareroot (2/pi) and solve for sigma. if yes i have done it results to a better theta as before :)